# Trouble With String Concatenation With Quotations While Using Selenium

Tags: string, selenium-webdriver, xpath, concatenation

I'm using Selenium to cycle through a directory of images and save one image at a time by searching a persons name and then using this line of code to get the image.

```
l = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@alt="John Smith"]')
file.write(l.screenshot_as_png)
```

I want to make it so I can change the name in the XPath so it can cycle through a list of names but every time I try to concatenate the XPath with a variable, it says the XPath doesn't exist.

This is the line of code I am using.

```
l = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@alt="' + name + '"]')
```

Message: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@alt="John Smith"]"}`

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: The syntax is correct, but the xpath argument needs a little tweak. Try this instead
l = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@alt='" + name + "']")

Comment: @SrinivasuKaki I tried this and it's still giving the same error message

Comment: Are saying `l = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@alt="John Smith"]')` _does_ work but `name = 'John Smith'` and `l = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@alt="' + name + '"]') ` _doesn't_ work?

Comment: can you share realted part of HTML code?

Comment: @ConalTuohy yes except name looks like this                                                     
  name = firstList[n1] + " " + lastList[n1]     and those lists are lists of first names and lists of last names

Comment: You need to show the complete HTML and complete source code. Include the source code which _does_ work (using XPath `'//*[@alt="John Smith"]'`), and its successful output, _as well as_ the source code which fails, and the exception it throws.

Comment: this should work `driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@alt="{name}"]')`